# Variable passed to from javascript to Python via AJAX - is not found

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

What I am trying to do is pass a value from my js to python via ajax (so that I could use it, later on, to apply some filtering to my database).

But, every time I am trying to get it in python- I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

Here is my js code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

// code to read selected table row cell data (values).
$("#myTable").on('click','button.btn.btn-primary',function(){
     // get the current row

     var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
     var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value

     var ids = {
        'user_id': col1
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(ids),
        type: 'POST',

        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

     alert(col1);
});

});
```

Here is my python:

```
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def index():
        if request.method == "POST":
            data = {}

            data['id'] = request.json['user_id']
            return jsonify(data)


       return render_template('index.html', title='Homepage')
```

The post request seems to be working ok. The error is given only when I try to fetch it python:

```
    data['id'] = request.json['user_id']
```

Any suggestion on how to go about it?

P.S I am not very good with js. Just starting out. Will appreciate any help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JSON.stringify for passing data into POST request. In POST request of AJAX, you have to pass whole object. on Server side in python you can retrive data by key which you have used in object key, in your code `user_id`

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ids,
        type: 'POST',

        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

I hope this will work, best of luck !!

Comment: changed as advised, but then it produces the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)

I am using request.get_json() in the flask view function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`data['id'] = request.json['user_id']`

try

`data: ids` in AJAX call and

`data['id'] = request.POST.get('user_id')` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get infos about a POST do you can use

```
request.get_json() # and you access the variable that you wanna

# This is another way
request.data # Will returns a dict

# When do you needs access a get parameters
request.args.get('param')
```

Comment: trying out your suggestion in my python code with:

     data = request.get_json(force=True)

        print(data)

But, that produces the following error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)